# USB3.2 backwards compatibility in KVM

Tags: usb, multiplexer, usb-device

I am making a KVM switch, and I have a USB 3.2 Gen 2x1 connector.

From what I have read, USB 3.0 and better has 9 pins, and USB 2.0 has 4. I have found a MUX which suits my needs: the [TMUXHS2414](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tmuxhs4212.pdf?ts=1701243727726&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F), but it has 4 pins out, SSTX+ and - and SSRX+ and -. These are for the superspeed USB.

My question is:
Do I need two muxes, one for the 3.0 and better (SSTX+, SSTX-, SSRX+, SSRX-), and one for the older usb 2.0 D+ and D-

Comment: Can you be more specific what you mean by what you should do to them? You obviously need them or it's not USB.

Comment: @Justme should I connect them to another mux/demux

Comment: Not the ground obviously. And likely a high speed data mux can't handle the amps or voltages required from the VBUS either. You still need to mux it somehow. Unless your USB KVM has a power supply of it's own and powers the keyboards etc.

Comment: What mux? Is there a part number? I would think the mux would handle both usb speeds

Comment: I can't write this as an answer because the question is closed - but it sounds like you're asking if the USB 2 pins (D- and D+) should be switched along with the USB 3 pins. And the answer is yes. You might need to add a second mux depending on the part you're using.  
This is because USB 2 and USB 3 are physically completely separate. It is possible for a device to connect only to the USB 2 pins, only to the USB 3 pins, or both. For example, if someone connects a keyboard (a USB 2 device) to your KVM, it will only use the D+/D- pins. If you don't switch those, then the keyboard won't work!

Comment: @AlexStuder OK, thank you. I will add this to the schematic now.

Comment: @VoltageSpike I am using the TMUXHS4212

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copying from my comment (with some modifications) now that the question is reopened:

---

Yes, you should mux both the USB 2 pins (D+/D-) and the USB 3 pins.

This is because USB 2 and USB 3 are physically completely separate. It is possible for a device to connect only to the USB 2 pins, only to the USB 3 pins, or both. For example, if someone connects a keyboard (a USB 2 device) to your KVM, it will only use the D+/D- pins. If you don't switch those, then the keyboard won't work!

The part number you are using (TMUXHS4214) only supports multiplexing the USB 3 pins. So, you will either need to add a separate USB 2 mux in parallel, or you can use a part that allows multiplexing both USB 2 and 3. For example, the [HD3SS6126](https://www.ti.com/product/HD3SS6126) is a different TI part that is also a 2:1 mux, but which can switch both USB 2 and 3 pins on the same chip.

Comment: Thank you so much!! BTW, how did you find that part? I searched the entire TI website and mouser website for something similar.